# Kosmos-2 ONNX Export For Offline Inference

Tags: flutter, artificial-intelligence, offline, onnx, onnxruntime

I want to use the huggingface kosmos2 model, and convert it to onnx so I can run offline inference in a flutter app. But I am stuck with converting it to onnx. I have tried torch.onnx.export, but here is the problem I get. I am able to export it, but the inferencing is completely wrong, and the output doesn't even have the right shape. Here is the code I have that runs it.

MY CODE:

```
inputs = sess.get_inputs()
outputs = sess.get_outputs()

for i, input_info in enumerate(inputs):
print(f"Input {i}: {input_info.name} shape: {input_info.shape}")

#for i in range(len(sess.get_outputs())):
#output_name = sess.get_outputs()[i].name
#print("Output name: ", output_name)
#output names: only last_hidden_state
for i, output_info in enumerate(inputs):
print(f"Output:", {output_info})
output_name = sess.get_outputs()[0]
print("Output 1:", output_name)
input_name = sess.get_inputs()[0]
```

OUTPUT:

```
Input 0: pixel_values shape: ['batch_size', 'num_channels', 'height', 'width']
Input 1: input_ids shape: ['batch_size', 'sequence_length']
Input 2: attention_mask shape: ['batch_size', 'sequence_length']
Input 3: image_embeds_position_mask shape: ['batch_size', 'sequence_length']
Output: {<onnxruntime.capi.onnxruntime_pybind11_state.NodeArg object at 0x000002A0462509B0>}
Output: {<onnxruntime.capi.onnxruntime_pybind11_state.NodeArg object at 0x000002A0120D1830>}
Output: {<onnxruntime.capi.onnxruntime_pybind11_state.NodeArg object at 0x000002A046F3E230>}
Output: {<onnxruntime.capi.onnxruntime_pybind11_state.NodeArg object at 0x000002A046F3DAB0>}
Output 1: NodeArg(name='last_hidden_state', type='tensor(float)', shape=['batch_size', 'sequence_length', 'hidden_size'])
```

MY CODE:

```
tokenInputs = tokenizer(text="A picture of", images=image, return_tensors="pt")
processor = AutoProcessor.from_pretrained("microsoft/kosmos-2-patch14-224")
print(tokenInputs['pixel_values'].shape)
#print("Token inputs:", tokenInputs)
print(tokenInputs['input_ids'].to(dtype=torch.int64).shape)
example = torch.zeros(1, 75)
#out_mat = sess.run(output_names=['last_hidden_state'], input_feed={'pixel_values': np.array(tokenInputs['pixel_values']), 'input_ids': np.array(tokenInputs['input_ids'].to(dtype=torch.int64)), 'attention_mask': np.array(tokenInputs['attention_mask'].to(dtype=torch.int64)), 'image_embeds_position_mask': np.array(tokenInputs['image_embeds_position_mask'].to(dtype=torch.int64))})
out_mat = sess.run(output_names=['last_hidden_state'], input_feed={'pixel_values':np.array(tokenInputs['pixel_values']), 'input_ids':np.array(example.to(dtype=torch.int64)), 'attention_mask': np.array(example.to(dtype=torch.int64)), 'image_embeds_position_mask': np.array(example.to(dtype=torch.int64))})
out_mat = torch.tensor(out_mat)
print(out_mat.shape)
print(out_mat)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Special tokens have been added in the vocabulary, make sure the associated word embeddings are fine-tuned or trained.
torch.Size([1, 1, 75, 2048])
tensor([[[[ 0.0831, -0.1343, -0.3462, ..., 0.5155, -0.2754, 0.0927],
[ 0.0808, -0.1369, -0.3498, ..., 0.5168, -0.2769, 0.0934],
[ 0.0780, -0.1400, -0.3541, ..., 0.5188, -0.2782, 0.0938],
...,
[ 0.0746, -0.1454, -0.3643, ..., 0.5329, -0.2984, 0.0831],
[ 0.0780, -0.1452, -0.3672, ..., 0.5332, -0.2987, 0.0835],
[ 0.0834, -0.1424, -0.3674, ..., 0.5337, -0.2981, 0.0835]]]])
```

The output last_hidden_state is supposed to have a shape of [batch_size, sequence_length, hidden_size], but this clearly doesn't. Also, the outputs are supposed to be integers, ranging from 0 to 64,000, but are instead floats. How can I solve this?